# Parse the string and convert into int

Tags: c#

I have the large number of below type of strings, 
and I need to take the height and width values and do the sum of the all height values  and take the max width value from the strings.

```
String value :

 "width: 123px ; height: 100px" 
           "width: 149px ; height: 1092px" 
           "width: 120px ; height: 190px" 
           "width: 123px ; height: 100px" 
              ...........

              .........
           "width: 123px ; height: 100px"
```

Can any one assist me on this.

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve it?

Comment: Yaa, by using List and string string split I splited to 123px and 1092px but then how I can splited to integers and take the sumations. and max values.

Comment: `String.Substring()`, `+`?

Comment: i suggest regular expression.

Comment: You should post your code that you have so far and show where the missing code should be.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you are trying to do overall.

Answer (score 0):

Tip: 
1 - Concatenate all strings into one big string as semicolon (;) separated values
2 - Replace all "px" with empty string
3 - Then split this big string using the semicolon. You'll get an array of strings. The array would look like below

```
width: 123
height: 100
width: 149
height: 1092
...............
```

4 - Now you could loop through this array and separate width and height values

Give it a try. I could've given you the code. But, then you'll not learn :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
String value = "\"width: 123px ; height: 100px\" \"width: 149px ; height: 1092px\" \"width: 120px ; height: 190px\" \"width: 123px ; height: 100px\" \"width: 123px ; height: 100px\"";

        System.Collections.Generic.List<int> widthArray = new System.Collections.Generic.List<int>();
        System.Collections.Generic.List<int> heightArray = new System.Collections.Generic.List<int>();
        string pattern = @"([\d]+[,.]{0,1})+";

        foreach (var v in value.Split('"'))
        {
            if (!v.Trim().Equals(string.Empty)){
            widthArray.Add(Convert.ToInt32(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(v.Split(';')[0], pattern).Value));
            heightArray.Add(Convert.ToInt32(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(v.Split(';')[1], pattern).Value));
            }
        }

        int maxWidht = widthArray.Max();
        int sumHeight = heightArray.Sum();
```

You split string to array using ", then split width and height using ';', remove unwanted characters using a regular expression, put those into list, get max and sum of those list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the strings are in something that can be enumerated over and they're always in the same format, you could do the following.

```
var maxWidth = values.Max(x => int.Parse(x.Split(';')[0].Substring(7, x.Split(';')[0].Length - 10)));
var totalHeight = values.Sum(x => int.Parse(x.Split(';')[1].Substring(8, x.Split(';')[1].Length - 10)));
```